# npm run build is adding "build" in the URL

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs3

We are using Laravel 9 and Vue 3. On our app.js we have.

```
import './bootstrap';
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';

const app = createApp({});


import ExampleComponent from './components/ExampleComponent.vue';
import ExampleComponent2 from './components/ExampleComponent2.vue';

const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: ExampleComponent },
    { path: '/about', component: ExampleComponent2 },
]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
    routes,
});

app.use(router);

app.mount('#app');
```

When we do `npm run dev`, we getting

- http://127.0.0.1:8000/
- http://127.0.0.1:8000/about

Which is correct.

The issue is when we do the `npm run build` for deployment, the URL showing is:

- http://127.0.0.1:8000/build/
- http://127.0.0.1:8000/build/about

There is "build" in the URL which is something we dont prefer. Is there a way to remove this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try to add `"homepage": ".",` in your package.json file.

Comment: @yakov I tried. and built again. Seems the same

Comment: I got this issue too. I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Just incase someone is having same issues.

It is an issue with the router. Update it to:

```
const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes, // short for `routes: routes`
});
```